# Tables not created on deployment of Java EE Application

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, persistence, ejb, javadb

I am running into the simple scenario that I started to create a Java EE App with EJB's.
As I changed the structure of some of the EJB's I thought it easiest to just remove the Tables in the Java DB (using the Netbeans interface). However, since the Application does deploy, but does not create any tables anymore, and I cannot find why.

Any suggestions how to 'debug' this?
There is no output on the server console in Netbeans at all anymore on deployment (this used to show warning that tables where not created because they already existed)

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="iDoms-server-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/iDomsServer</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

(GlassFish 3.1 and Netbeans 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, a restart of Netbeans and a clean build fixed the issue.